# In ΔABC prove that sides are in $AP$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry

In ΔABC, if $$\tan\left(\frac{A}{2}\right)=\frac{5}{6}$$ and $$\tan\left(\frac{B}{2}\right)=\frac{20}{37}$$ prove that sides lengths $a$, $b$ and $c$, when sorted, form an arithmetic progression

**My work**:-

since, $\cos(\frac{A}{2})$=$\sqrt\frac{s(s-a)}{bc}$ and  $\sin(\frac{A}{2})$=$\sqrt\frac{(s-b)(s-c)}{bc}$ where $s$=$\frac{a+b+c}{2}$ so $\tan(\frac{A}{2})$=$\frac{\sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}}{s(s-a)}$

let, $\sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}$=$\Delta$ similarly,$\tan(\frac{B}{2})$=$\frac{\sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}}{s(s-b)}$=$\frac{\Delta}{s(s-b)}$ also $\tan(\frac{A}{2})$=$\frac{\Delta}{s(s-a)}$

Now, $\frac{\tan\left(\frac{A}{2}\right)}{\tan\left(\frac{B}{2}\right)}$=$\frac{\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)}{\left(\frac{20}{37}\right)}$=$\frac{\frac{\Delta}{s(s-a)}}{\frac{\Delta}{s(s-b)}}$ finally $\frac{37}{24}$=$\frac{s-b}{s-a}$ $\Rightarrow$ after some simplyfications, 37(b+c-a)=24(a+c-b)

it becomes, 61b+13c=61a,

but..... it is not the condition required for Arithmatic Progression i.e. 2b=a+c.

Comment: You want to prove that $a,b,c$ are in AP, but what is AP?

Comment: Arithmetic progression, perhaps....?

Comment: What is the segment AP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From given, 
$$\tan\left(\frac{A+B}2\right) = \frac{5/6+20/37}{1-(5/6)(20/37)} = \frac{305}{122} = 2.5$$

$$\tan\frac C2 = \tan\left(\frac\pi2-\frac{A+B}2\right) = \frac{1}{\tan\left(\frac{A+B}2\right)} = \frac25$$

Let the radius of the inscribed circle be $r$. Then

$$a = \frac{r}{\tan\frac B2}+\frac r{\tan\frac C2} = \left(\frac{37}{20} + \frac{5}{2}\right)r = \frac{174}{40}r\\
b = \frac{r}{\tan\frac C2}+\frac r{\tan\frac A2} = \left(\frac{5}{2} + \frac{6}{5}\right)r = \frac{37}{10}r\\
c = \frac{r}{\tan\frac A2}+\frac r{\tan\frac B2} = \left(\frac{6}{5} + \frac{37}{20}\right)r = \frac{305}{100}r
$$

The rest should be obvious.